# My Style sheet path, and JQuery file path always cracked and had to remane the files name each time when do update on them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

My Style sheet path, and J-Query file path  always cracked  and had to re-mane the files name each time when do update on them.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?php echo $css;?>mainnew2.css">
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?php echo $css;?>mainnew2.css">

Comment: What do you mean "cracked"? they won't load? won't update?...

Comment: echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href=".'$css'.mainnew2.css">'; CTRL+F5 if you change someting in any repository css,js,ts etc. browser do cache

Comment: Append a parameter to the URL (e.g. `main.css?v=3`) if you want to avoid the cache. This could be done in PHP by getting the last-modified date of the file in question. You may want to configure the caching for your web server, potentially in a `.htaccess` file.